# Grid-like pattern on toolstrip button image

Tags: c#, image, random, grid

I cannot wrap my head around this, but it appears that on some images on a toolstrip button a gridlike pattern appears. It happens after a random number of starts of the program, and only on some buttons.

[This](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qMvHt3mHSqrIQwLVUWeSFNWEk6NVUzO0) is an example of what happens... If someone knows what it's caused by, I'd really appreciate the help.
Thank you

Comment: I haven't seen this in my life. It might be related to your build/platform configuration. Try adding the same images somewhere else. Also check the original image size with its actual size on screen

Comment: What do you mean somewhere else... it's pretty obvious that it's not the image itself... If I open them in any other way they don't do this, and it also doesn't happen from the first time... And the on-screen image is 48px as the file is... It should look like the Stop button instead...

Comment: So you got different or random outcome for exactly same kind/size of image? It's not enough for me to guess. Try to use those images in other controls And other systems

Comment: Also try to mess with image properties. Like UseLayoutRounding, snap tO deviCe pixels,...

Comment: @Bijan LayoutRounding and snap to device pixels are not options that I can use, for they are nowhere... And the program in other systems does exactly the same...